# state rendering in react.js

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a very simple question which has been bugging me. I am relatively new to react and having issues with state. If I have a component that creates a state variable like below

```
const [state, setState] = useState(null)
```

and let in the code I do something like this...

```
setState(50)
```

Changing the state forces a re-render which in turn re-initializes the state variable as null. What am I doing wrong? I want the app the re-render when state changes and leave state as 50 in this example but when it re-renders it re-initializes the state as null. Super strange.

actual code...

```
const ConnectBackend = props => {
    const [moisture, setMoisture] = useState(null)

    let temp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    var i = 0;
    function myLoop() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            setMoisture(temp[i]);
            console.log(moisture)
            i++;
            if (i < 10) {
                myLoop();
            }
        }, 3000)
    }
  
    myLoop(); 
}
```

Comment: `useState(null)` only initializes the state to null when the component is first mounted; subsequent renders do not reset it to `null`. Can you paste more of your code? Where are you calling `useState` and `setState`?

Comment: Just in case your setState snippet is literal, setState receives a function as argument where you return the value you want. `setState(() => {return 50})`

Comment: I added a very simple code example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you using the setState? If you do it like so, it shouldn't be an issue.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(null)
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setState(50);
  }, []);
  
  return <p>{state}</p>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

If you did it like this, this will end in too many rerenders, as after the state update the component function will be called again and update the state again, then call itself again and so on -> loop

```js
// DO NOT DO THIS
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(null);

  setState(50);

  return <p>Hello CodeSandbox</p>;
}
```

UPDATE: After reading your comments and the updated code. You might want to get into more reactive way of dealing with this. Go check this out

```js
const { useEffect, useState, useMemo } = React;

let temp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const ConnectBackend = (props) => {
  const [i, setI] = useState(0);
  const [myInterval, setMyInterval] = useState();

  const moisture = useMemo(() => temp[i], [i]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setI((oldI) => oldI + 1);
    }, 1000);
    setMyInterval(interval);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (i > 8) clearInterval(myInterval);
  }, [myInterval, i]);

  return <p>{moisture}</p>;
};


ReactDOM.render(<ConnectBackend />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yes this is my problem! What is a simple solution?

Comment: Ah. I got it. I will post below. Thank you. This is the issue. I guess I need to read up on useEffect and how they work.

Comment: @JustinOberle I have updated my answer with a code example of how this could be done after reading your update, hope it helps

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Can you comment on what clearInterval is doing and also how the second useEffect works? I can't quite understand the i > 8 part

Comment: So you return a function in the useEffect that will be run once the component unmounts so that it will remove any running intervals. Otherwise once the component is unmounted the interval would still trigger and produce an error. clearInterval removes that interval. The second useEffect is the "exit". We have an effect that will end the interval after 10 iterations, without the second effect the interval would never end.